# Add default classification to Esri ASCII Raster?

Tags: classification, las, ascii, laz

I have some .ASC data files from Wales Govt. LiDAR data.  I converted it to LAZ using LasTools, but when I try to use the data in a third party app, I get an error saying that the data is unclassified.

I am good with data files and processing, but I do not know how to change the ASC data to make it classified.

Could anyone direct me on how to add some default classification to the data?

Answer (score 2):

The [Welsh website](http://lle.gov.wales/Catalogue/Item/LidarCompositeDataset/?lang=en) allows you to download DTM and DSM in ASCII format. It is not raw lidar data. Classification of lidar data as I understand it is found in data that is in **LAS** format not ASCII. ESRI help has a useful page on the [classification in LAS data](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/lidar-point-classification.htm).

So all you have done is converted elevation data that has no concept of classification encoded into it into a format that can store that concept but as it came from your ASCII data everything is unclassified.

Comment: Thanks for the detail.  My intention is to edit the data to apply a classification, ie Ground (2), and make Laz files.  I have used LasTools to add classification, convert to height data and add classification...

Comment: lasground_new -i .\LAZ\%1.laz -o .\GROUND\%1.laz -set_classification 2
  lasheight -i .\GROUND\%1.laz -o .\HEIGHT\%1.laz
  lasclassify -i .\HEIGHT\%1.laz -o .\CLASSIFY\%1.laz